# How can I hook up NSWindow's initialFirstResponder when using Storyboards in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I'm frustrated with the wall that using storyboards seems to put between NSWindows/NSWindowControllers and NSViews/NSViewControllers. A specific example: What good is the initialFirstResponder outlet on NSWindow if the whole view hierarchy is in a separate scene and can't be referenced?

I'd like to make the window called "progred"'s initialFirstResponder the "Content View" view from the View Controller Scene, but you can't make IBOutlet references across scenes. I'd be perfectly happy to put the ViewController and the Window in the same scene, but I can't seem to get that to work with all of the dragging/dropping I've tried to do from one scene to another, or even trying to add a new one from the toolbox. It seems that you're required to use a segue relationship to assign a NSViewController to a NSWindow.

I've googled but I'm not finding anything on this problem which might just mean I'm missing something obvious as I'm pretty new to Storyboards as I can't imagine I'm the first to notice this :).

[image: Scene Heirarchy]

Comment: Given the WWDC 2015 session titles, I have a strong hunch IB's well-known deficiencies of late will be addressed with an update we'll see this Monday.

Answer (score 3):

I've been going through just this in swift (Xcode 6.3.1).  IB appears to be unable to do what we want despite all the doco and advice saying "control drag....". My (eventual) solution/workaround was to set it in code, in viewWillAppear, of the view controller.  I'd tried a variety of approaches until I encounter some apple doco that declared that the initialFirstResponder must be set BEFORE the window displayed.  Hope this helps.

By the way, watch out for the default Window behaviour being "restorable" which seems to restart the (rebuilt) app with the focus in the last field the app was killed in....sigh